# How to remove everything that begins with x in PHP array?

Tags: php, arrays

I have array:

```
Array
(
    [0] => #EX-X
    [1] => #EX-DURATION:5
    [2] => X-MEDIA
    [3] => #EXDATE-TIME
    [4] => YEAR
    [5] => color
    [6] => #EX-DURATION:10
)
```

How to remove everything that begins with **#EX** in array?

Can't figure out!

Final result should be:

```
Array
(
    [0] => X-MEDIA
    [1] => YEAR
    [2] => color
)
```

Comment: any code sample that you tried?

Comment: @prasun No, don't have any sample.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With [array_filter](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) :

```
$arrayFiltered = array_filter($yourArray, function($val) {
    return strpos($val, '#EX') !== 0;
});
$resultArray = array_values($arrayFiltered);
```

Comment: Nice, clean solution. Never use `array_filter()` before... will remember it for future use.

Comment: Oops! If you want contiguous array keys after this you'll also need array_values($arrayFiltered) afterwards

Comment: Thanks, nice and clean code. I tried with `array_filter`, but didn't try with `strpos` function.

Answer (score 1):

A simple loop with a check for `#EX` at the start of each value.

```
$array = array( ... ); //array with "dirty" values
$new_array = array();
foreach($array AS $val)
{
    if(substr($val, 0, 3) != '#EX')
    {
        $new_array[] = $val;
    }
}
```